# Drag dot around circle beyond < 0 and > 360

Tags: javascript, user-interface, trigonometry

I am playing around with a wheel UI.
And one thing I would like for it to do is count beyond < 0 and > 360

A demo says a thousand words: http://jsfiddle.net/p0eabyj3/

```
mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offset.left);
mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offset.top);

var rads = Math.atan2(mouseY - center, mouseX - center);
var x = 100 * Math.cos(rads) + center;
var y = 100 * Math.sin(rads) + center;
var _degree = (rads > 0 ? rads : (fullCircle + rads)) * 360 / fullCircle;
...
```

It is placing a dot using basic trig on a circle when moving your mouse around.

The values I am getting is from 0-359. But I would like it to continuously count above 360 when moving clockwise, so it always counts upwards no mater how many times the dot goes clockwise around the circle, and count downwards when going clockwise.

Comment: Interesting... You will need a new way of *counting*. Currently, it is undetermined what should happen if you move the mouse from left to right, i.e., moving 'directly' from -180° to +180°. Would that be counted as "plus" or "minus" a full circle? (I think I'd avoid this issue by not updating the position all the time, but only when the mouse is near the red circle.)

Comment: In theory the numbers -180 and 180 would almost always be with a decimal — with the human error-margin taking into account — and therefore you would always know if it had moved around a full circle or not. Writting this did give me a lead in the correction direction, combined with @thedouglenz approach (check [fiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/w7f13c5n/1/) ) I would however love for this to be solved via plain math ... But you can't have it all.

Answer (score 2):

Answer is here -> http://jsfiddle.net/w7f13c5n/1/

```
if(last_degree - degree > 180)
    count += 360;
else if (last_degree - degree < -180)
    count -= 360;
```

answer is a combination between thedouglenz and Jongware. It would however be a perfect answer if this was clean math. But this solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might try some logic like the following:

```
last_degree = degree;
degree = (rads > 0 ? rads : (fullCircle + rads)) * 360 / fullCircle;

if(degree - last_degree > 0) res+= 1;
else res -= 1;
```

Here's a fiddle with the whole thing: http://jsfiddle.net/w7f13c5n/

Comment: Your fiddle never goes above 360.

Comment: Better now, but it's off by a factor of 2. Each time around the circle is only 180 instead of 360.

Comment: Actually, it's not 180, either. I'm not quite sure what it's doing, because when I go back to my start position, it doesn't become 0.

Comment: It's just checking to see that you have moved in a clockwise direction at all and incrementing a counter. Otherwise it decrements the counter. It probably varies with the speed the mouse cursor is moved

Comment: The fiddle has a few issues, if you move around quickly it does not map the number to the correct number of times you go around the circle, also if you move from 360 < > 0 it also jumps the numbers a lot as there is a big difference between previous degree and current degree. I guess you could add a big array of if conditions for this and maybe end up with something that would be kind precise, but this problem must be solvable via math.